# How to perform async axios call to REST api and update the store (redux thunk is confusing)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

So, I have to make an asynchronous request to REST api, I have read about redux thunk, but I am still a bit confused with that so I was trying to make an asynchronous request inside of reducer

Here is a working example, it returns plain json object

```
 return Object.assign({}, state,
 { texts: state.texts.concat({ data: 'some text'}) })
```

But when it comes to the network request it doesn't give any error, it just looks like return doesn't work, so that's why my components can't update

```
axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(res => {
    return Object.assign({}, state,
 { texts: state.texts.concat({ data: action.payload }) })
})
```

Even setTimeout() does not work...

```
setTimeout(()=> {
    return Object.assign({}, state,
{ texts: state.texts.concat({ data: 'some text' }) })
},100)
```

Complete code as some people asked...
**Reducer:**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const LOAD = 'LOAD'

let initialState = {
   texts: [
      { data: 'Orinary text' }
   ]
}

export let textReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case LOAD:
         axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(res => {
            return Object.assign({}, state,
               { texts: state.texts.concat({ data: action.payload }) })
         })
      default:
         return state
   }
}

export let loadActionCreator = () => {
   return { type: LOAD, payload: 'res.data.message ' }
}
```

**Store:**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { textReducer } from './text-reducer'

let reducers = combineReducers({
   textReducer: textReducer
})

export let store = createStore(reducers)
```

**Component:**

```
import { loadActionCreator } from './Redux/text-reducer'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return ({
      state: state}
  )
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return ({
      loadActionCreator: () => dispatch(loadActionCreator())}
  )
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.state.textReducer.texts.map(el => {
        return (
          <div>{el.data}</div>
        )
      })}
      <button onClick={() => props.loadActionCreator()}>Add data</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import { subscribe } from 'redux'
import { store } from './Redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

let rerender = (store) => {
   ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root'))
}

rerender(store)

store.subscribe(() => {
   rerender(store)
})
```

Comment: Could you show a full example, so we have a bit more context of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Webber: done, I added only redux part

Comment: @Lucifer: You should also share `action` files and `component` files. Typical flow is from `component` to `action` to `reducer` and back to `component`

Comment: @Isaac: I've posted all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so lets break this down.

> I have read about redux thunk, but I am still a bit confused with that so I was trying to make an asynchronous request inside of reducer.

Redux Thunk came up with their library exactly for what you're trying to do. So you're in the right direction. See their their [movitation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation) below.

> Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action. The thunk can be used to delay the dispatch of an action, or to dispatch only if a certain condition is met. The inner function receives the store methods dispatch and getState as parameters.
>
> An action creator that returns a function to perform asynchronous dispatch:
>
> ```
> const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';
>
> function increment() {
>   return {
>     type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
>   };
> }
>
> function incrementAsync() {
>   return dispatch => {
>     setTimeout(() => {
>       // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
>       dispatch(increment());
>     }, 1000);
>   };
> }
> ```

However, you're trying to perform an async call, without any async middleware. This is pretty hard to do (properly) unless you perform the call from the component, in a thunk or using other design patterns like sagas.

Lets stick with Redux Thunk and see what your implementation would look like. I've created a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-thunk-example-zfw6r), sticking to the very basics.

The relevant part is that you only had action creators, but not thunks:

```
// Action creators
export const textLoaded = text => {
  return {
    type: LOADED,
    text
  };
};

// Thunks
export function textLoadRequest() {
  return dispatch => {
    /**
     * If you want to use axios, to recieve data; replace the
     * `setTimeout` with `axios.get()` and perform the dispatch
     * in the `then()` callback.
     */
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(textLoaded("text after timeout"));
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

Please don't hesitate to give feedback on the usefulness of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You got the concept wrong. Network request with should be perform at action files instead of reducers.

Reducers are the location where you want to update your state from redux-store, based on the API result you got from redux-action. That is reason why most of the time you will see a `switch` statement in almost all your reducers, reason being your `actions` can dispatch any `type` and you need a `switch` statement to update the store based on certain type

Comment: Actions don't help aswell, becasue it requires to be object returned

Comment: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. 'axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(res => {
      return { type: LOAD, payload: res.data.message }
   })'

Comment: Default `action` expects to return plain object with a type as key. That's why you need the help of `redux-thunk`, which allows you to `dispatch`, instead of returning single object

Comment: @Lucifer: As shown at https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk , you can use `dispatch` statement instead of `return` in `action creator`